# CSS3: Making Overlapping Div

Tags: css, overlapping

I am trying to create [this effect](http://i49.tinypic.com/22c3du.jpg) by using HTML in UIWebView control of iOS. The goal is to create the effect of progress bar on the listing. So far I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tFn78/4/) but as you see, by adding a padding on diV makes everything messed up. How can I achieve similar effect? I have no issue of using table but seems that would be more difficult.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you supplied you have this div:

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:0%; background-color: hsl(30,100%,59%);width:30%;z-index:10;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Just add "top: 0px;" to it so that it becomes

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:0%; top: 0px; background-color: hsl(30,100%,59%);width:30%;z-index:10;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

And it will look correct.

Edit: And then give the LI elements `position: relative` to make it work with multiple elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/tFn78/9

Another version which is a bit cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/v7zNn/ and adjusts to variable height of the title.

Comment: the issue with top:0 is that when the markup is repeated(for representing new records) it will override the overlay div

Comment: Just add position: relative; to all your your outer most DIVs or LIs to solve that

Comment: sweet. So it was all about setting the parent element as relative

Comment: Exactly :) Anything that's absolute will be relative to any outer container that is absolute or relative.

Comment: There is an issue, adding too much text disturbs the div. See http://jsfiddle.net/tFn78/27/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U8weV/ 
I added width, display: inline-block, white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis. The title will now be cut of with three dots if it's too long. Otherwise you could just try adjusting those "width:70%":s to make the percentages to the left and the number to the right smaller

Comment: So I have to chop it off anyway? multi line will mess it up? Though its not a bad option

Comment: Should be possible. But might have to refine that HTML a bit. Looking into it.

Comment: I think it's Ok. Don't waste time. it does not look bad, keeping in mind to use it on iPhone/iPad's WebView control, I think it's fine.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Well, @Volatil3 I couldn't help myself. Try this and see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/v7zNn/

Comment: This is not related to this question btu related to same project, Check this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922097/css3-positioning-in-padding-elements), can you figure this out?  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use nested divs and give the inner Div a percentage width.

```
<div><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

And CSS:

```css
div {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
}
.inner {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Since divs are block level element they have a 100% width by default so you don't need to explicitly specify it for the outer div if that is sufficient.

Another possibility would be to use a background gradient and just move alter the background-position.

Comment: you mean linear gradient and vary size based on percentage?

Comment: You could set a linear gradient with a background-size of 200% and the adjust background-position-x.

Comment: Will be slower for UIWebView on iOS. But nice tip for web based stuff.

Comment: The rendering for UIWebView is on par with mobile Safari. As far as I am aware it is only JavaScript that lacks in performance. That said, I had issues with really large gradients (like full screen on iPad with transparent items on top) but not with small UI items.