# CSS3: Positioning in padding elements

Tags: css, positioning

The link of JSfiddle [recipe](http://jsfiddle.net/8xPay/2/) is given here. I want to keep the vertical line set as **#imgLine** fixed at the bottom as a separator between ULs. I want to shift encircled checkmark Image to right, setting the left or padding left in **.rec** class is shifting bottom line, I am failed to figure out how to do it. The desire output is to keep line fix at bottom and I can shift content to left.

Thhanks

Comment: Sorted it out based on the answer of one of the commentors in my previous question: http://jsfiddle.net/8xPay/11/ Thanks @Charlie

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. Love when answers are able to answers other questions.